# Android app UI design - Hangman

Tags: android, user-interface

I am fairly new to Android. Just getting learning the ropes and fumbling around at the moment.
I thought a good way to learn a few new concepts would be to try my hand at a few apps.

This app is a replica of the popular word game - Hangman.

[image]

I've created a very basic UI consisting of 26 buttons, each corresponding to a letter, and some imageview's which make up the dashes you see in the middle of the screen.

Now comes the problem. I'm trying to figure out how to include a programatically rendered drawing of a stick figure in the top right corner of the layout.

I went through the API, and there seems to be several ways to do this, but I'm not sure which way would be the most efficient?

The layout shown above basically consists of 3 relativelayouts.

I would really appreciate if someone would be kind enough to point me in the right direction. I'm not asking for a whole block of code as an answer. What I would like is just a prod in the right direction.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html). You can just add a SurfaceView and draw lines on it.
Otherwise you could just have an image for every state of the man, and change them.

But I'd recommend Canvas with SurfaceView because of the low resources, and flexibility.